# How to fix bottom gray bar in SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I develop some app to iPad and iPhone, but I have a problem with a gray bar up to the TabBar.

I have tried `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`
but it didn't work. It works on iPad, but when I use SplitView the problem comes. Gray bottom view on the Screen. I have this problem on my iPhone, when I push view like that

```
splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller), sender: nil)
```

On iPad it works when I use split view full screen:
[Great size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt86J.png)

But when I resize SplitView it breaks: [Gray bottom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6BEf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I change constraints when traitcollectiondidchanged.